# Spark dataframe column in jooq select query

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark, jooq

I am reading from csv file using rdd and get only one column from dataframe and convert it to array using scala toArray.

After that, I am using this array in a sql to check whether one field value in this array or not.

I am using Postgresql and jooq 3.11, but how much I try, I can not render the sql as it needs to be.

in below code is `Array[String]`. However, it is not generating the sql. I got these errors while I was experimenting on this issue with `inline()` and `DSL.array`, and `in()` versions of the same question:

`Cannot interpret argument of type class org.jooq.impl.QuantifiedSelectImpl as a Field
Type class org.jooq.impl.Array is not supported in dialect DEFAULT
operator does not exist: character varying = character varying[]
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

```
val ast = select(columns:_*).from(tableName).where(field("y").equal(inline(y))).and(field("x").equal(any(x))).asTable("t")
```

How can I use `Array[String]` to compare if my column value in this array.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using source code generation to avoid this problem in general

It is generally recommended to use the jOOQ code generator because it does the following work for you, instead of you having to think of this all the time.

#### Work around this problem in your specific case

In many cases, jOOQ needs to know the correct data type of a `Field<T>` expression to bind variables correctly, especially when it comes to PostgreSQL arrays. Type inference for these array types is not as strong as one might hope in PostgreSQL. So to make sure everything works as expected, you'll have to write things like:

```java
field("y", SQLDataType.VARCHAR)
field("x", SQLDataType.VARCHAR)
```

If you don't supply a data type, jOOQ will simply infer `SQLDataType.OBJECT`, which corresponds to `Types.OTHER` in JDBC, or `java.lang.Object`. So it doesn't know how to bind an array, and a few type inference problems in Java (and Scala) might even lead to the wrong overload being chosen, e.g. among the `Field.equal()` overloads. In your case, [`Field.equal(T)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Field.html#equal(T)) was chosen but you wanted [`Field.equal(QuantifiedSelect)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Field.html#equal(org.jooq.QuantifiedSelect))

Comment: my field("x") is varchar type, and my x in the any is some regular scala array that contains strings, not a field or a table. While I was searching, I have also noticed that jooq has a problem with casting, and you should use plain sql to avoid that.

Comment: @TolgaBilbey: 1) You should be able to pass that scala array once you use `field("x", SQLDataType.VARCHAR)`. Try it. 2) Can you be specific about that "problem with casting"? Where did you find that recommendation?